# FitzHugh- Nagumo Model conversion into state space

Tags: dynamical-systems, physics, mathematical-physics

Is it possible to convert the Fitzhugh Nagumo model into State-space? Is it done using linearization using Jacobian?

Comment: What is the current state that you want to transform it from? If you want to linearize the non-linear system, you would need to provide a stable or almost stable basis state. // Are you asking about a scalar version or the PDE like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661084/what-is?

Comment: I was looking for a way to convert  the FHN equations, the  differential equations in the [link] (https://sites.me.ucsb.edu/~moehlis/APC591/tutorials/tutorial2/node7.html) to State-space form  which looks like (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/control_systems/control_systems_state_space_model.htm)

Comment: Your system, which is also very similar to the Vander Pol oscillator, has a non-linear part that is defining for its behavior. You can not simply squeeze it into a linear form. Also, the form from the second link is for linear control problems, with a state $X$ (of the linear ODE system), input $U$ and output $Y$. Here you have a different structure. The form in the first link is already an explicit first-order system, which is the "normal form" for ODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cite
\begin{align}
\varepsilon \frac{dv}{dt}&=F(v)-w+I\\
\frac{dw}{dt}&=v-\gamma w
\end{align}
with $F(v)=v(1-v)(v+a)$, $ε\ll1$ and all other variables constants ($I$ might also be a time-variable external input like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256309/matlab-euler-explicit).

This is already an explicit first-order system with state space $(v,w)\in\Bbb R^2$. While linearizations at equilibrium points serve to determine the nature of these, in general there is no linear formulation of this system, the non-linear term $F(v)$ is essential.

---

The expected behavior is that the first equation forces $v$ in time-scales $\sim ε$ to "jump" to one of the roots of $F(v)=w-I$ with a negative $F$ derivative. The second equation moves $w$ relatively slowly towards equality with $v/γ$. This includes situations where the current solution branch of $F(v)=w-I$ ends in a fold bifurcation, so that $v$ has to jump to the other solution branch (which always exist as $F$ is cubic with negative leading coefficient).

[image: some plots of different situations]

As one can see in these plots with $ε=0.01$, solutions jump quickly to the cubic curve and then move in direction of the line of the second equation. If there is an intersection, it is a stable equilibrium. If there is no intersection before the minimum or maximum, the solution jumps to the other value of this level. If the line is arranged to pass below the minimum and above the maximum like in the third panel, a limit cycle gets established.